# Java Program: How to display the right pay amount?

Tags: java

So the instructions for my program are:
Write a program that calculates the amount a person would earn over a period of time if his  or her salary is one penny the first day, two pennies the second day, and continues to double every day. The program should display a table showing the salary for each day, and then show the total pay at the end of the period. The output should be displayed in a dollar Problem amount, not the number of pennies.

Input Validation: Do not accept a numher less than t for the numher of days worked.

This is my program so far:

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PENNIES {

       public static void main(String[] args)
    {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    int day, DaysWorked; double finalsalary, currentpay; 


    finalsalary = 0;
    currentpay = 0.01;


    System.out.println("How many days did you work?");
    DaysWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (DaysWorked < 1)
{System.out.println("Invalid input: " + DaysWorked + ", please try again!");

    }

    System.out.println("Days Worked                         Money Earned");
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");



    for (day = 1; day <= DaysWorked; day++)
    {
      currentpay = currentpay * 2;
      System.out.println(  day + "\t \t \t \t" + currentpay);
      finalsalary += currentpay;

    }
System.out.println("Your total salary is  \n $" + formatter.format (+ finalsalary));



  }
```

It keeps adding the values wrong, the first day it shows: "0.02" pennies, which should be "0.01". How can I fix this?

UPDATE**

This is my final program, thank you guys:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat; //Formats the decimal (cents)
import java.util.*;

public class PENNIES 
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int day, DaysWorked, run = 0; double finalsalary, currentpay;  
    do {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    NumberFormat AmericanMoney = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); //Converts final salary into US dollars

    finalsalary = 0;
    currentpay = 0.01;

    System.out.println("How many days did you work?");
    DaysWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (DaysWorked < 1){ //User cannot input less than 1 day
    System.out.println("Invalid input: " + DaysWorked + ", please try again!");

    }

    System.out.println("Days Worked                      Money Earned"); //Displays a table with results
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");



    for (day = 1; day <= DaysWorked; day++) //Loops the currentpay with the respective day of work
    {      
      System.out.println(  day + "\t \t \t \t" + currentpay);
      finalsalary += currentpay;      
      currentpay = currentpay * 2;

    }
    System.out.println("Your total salary is  \n " + AmericanMoney.format (+ finalsalary) + "\n");

    }
    while (run < 1); //Restarts the program automatically



 }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you define the variable:

```
currentpay = 0.01;
```

Then you double it:

```
currentpay = currentpay * 2;
```

Then you print it:

```
System.out.println(  day + "\t \t \t \t" + currentpay);
```

Well, `0.01 * 2` equals `0.02`.  So... it prints `0.02`.

If you want to double it *after* it's printed, then double it after it's printed:

```
System.out.println(  day + "\t \t \t \t" + currentpay);
finalsalary += currentpay;
currentpay = currentpay * 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Now when I input a high number of days worked, the calculations get messed up. Let's say that on day 96, the current pay is " 6.189700196426902E24"

Comment: That's because the formula for any given day's paycheck is 2^(days worked - 1). For 96 days, that's 2^95. Java's double is 64-bit. You should use Math.BigDecimal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html . Furthermore, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html specifies that neither float nor double should be used for currencies, and that you should use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: Interesting. Can you show me how to use in my program?

Answer (score 0):

If you work one day, it's executing the for loop once. Every execution of the for loop doubles your currentpay of 0.01. That's why you're getting a 0.02.

A simple fix is to set currentpay to 0.005, so the first day doubles it and returns 0.01, second day doubles the 0.01, and so forth.

Another solution is to code a different behaviour for the first day. In your problem you state that "his or her salary is one penny the first day, two pennies the second day, and continues to double every day", so first day should just set salary to 0.01, and only start your for loop (which doubles the pay) from day 2. If you need code for this ask in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> This program is not completed first of all you need a variable for hours but here's how you find how much you made if you were working 1 hour a day. 
>   You had to multiply currentpay which i change from 0.01 to 11 because that's minimum wage x day because you want to find how much they got paid each day, but if you want to figure it out  the amount of hours they worked, then you have to make an hour variable and multiply it by that instead.

```
 for (day = 1; day <= DaysWorked; day++)
{
  currentpay = currentpay * day;
  System.out.println(  day + "\t \t \t \t" + currentpay);
  finalsalary += currentpay;
```

Comment: @NeilsMedereck   Also if you want to show the currency use the Locale import     `Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);` `System.out.println("United States: " + currency.getSymbol(Locale.US));`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside:
If you want to print out or represent dollar values nicely with little effort, you can use the NumberFormat Class.

More specifically, you can write this

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

.
.

NumberFormat canadianMoney = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
.
.

System.out.println("Final salary is: " + canadianMoney.format(finalSalary) );
```

The format method returns a String formatted in the currency specified with Locale. You can of course use any Locale (I think the default is USA/North American -- the $ sign). It automatically rounds to the cent.

So for example it would return 5.999 as '$6.00' and 24.3456 as '$24.35'.

Just a little tidbit of information if you'd find it useful to represent monetary amounts in the future. Also, to round values to certain decimal places and keep them as 'doubles', the BigDecimal class is a good idea if ever you find the need.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PenniesForPay

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
```

String inputString;

```
    int pennies;      // Penny accumulator

    int totalPay;     // Total pay accumulator

    int maxDays;      // Max number of days

    int day;          // Day counter


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int days;

 //   inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("For how many days will you work? ");
    days = sc.nextInt();
     

    maxDays = days;

    

    // Validate the input

    while (maxDays < 1){

         inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The number of days " +

               "must be at least 1.\nEnter the number of days: ");

         

         maxDays = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

      }

    

      day = 1;

      pennies = 1;

      totalPay = 0;

       

      while (day <= maxDays)
      {
         // Display the day number and pennies earned.

          System.out.println("Day:\t" + day + "\nPennies Earned:\t" + pennies);

          

         // Accumulate the total pay.

        totalPay = totalPay + pennies;

          

         // Increment for the next day.

         day++;

          

         // Double the number of pennies.

         pennies = pennies * 2;

      }

      

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total pay: $" + totalPay / 100.0);

}
```

}